# Visual Studio разрядность приложения.

Tags: windows, ide, c++, visual-studio, x86-64

При создании(или после создания) приложения в Visula Studio 2012, как указать для скольки разрядной версии Windows оно создаётся? Т.е., что это будет 32 разрядное, или 64 разрядное приложение.

Answer (score 2):

Окно Visual Studio -> Панель "Стандартные" -> Раскрывающийся список "Платформы решения"
В VS2010 это выглядит так:
[image]

Соответственно, выбираете в каком режиме нужно производить построение: в Debug || в Release